# RASA /Dialogflow to SNIPS NLU

Tags: dialogflow-es, rasa-nlu, nlp, snips

Does somebody know a good Rasa NLU or Dialogflow converter to SNIPS format?
Maybe with an Graphical User Interface.

There are some that convert from rasa to DF and vice versa but I cant seem to find a converter to SNIPS.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could translate the training files.

If the size of your training set is manageable you may achieve this by:

- rewriting it with [chatito](https://github.com/rodrigopivi/Chatito), that supports both formats,
- generating the training set in the Rasa format and check that it's consistent with the original
- and finally by generating the training set in the Snips format